# Display pagination in own shortcode (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I have code for display products with stock quantity = 1 item.
Everything is fine, but I want to add pagination for this.

Here is my code:

```
add_shortcode( 'limit_stock_products', 'limit_of_stock_products_shortcode' );
   
function limit_of_stock_products_shortcode() {
 
   $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
       

      'meta_query' => array(
         array(
             'key'     => '_stock',
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'value'   => '1',
            'compare' => '=',
            

         )
      ),
      'fields' => 'ids',
   );
    
   $product_ids = get_posts( $args ); 
   $product_ids = implode( ",", $product_ids );
    
   return do_shortcode("[products ids='$product_ids']");
 
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

I tried add 'pagination' => true,
Not working.

Comment: This should be the proper shortcode - [products ids="$product_ids" limit="4" columns="4" paginate=true ]. This will show 4 products per page in 4 columns. Read more about woo shortcodes here - https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#products

Comment: Thanks. I know woocommerce shortcodes.
Your shortcode is not working. I need to display products wits stock quantity = 1 (last product in stock).
If I change 'posts_per_page' =>  -1, , them I see all products with stock = 1. But I want to add pagination for display 4 products per page (for example).